# How to print unicode to console in Eiffel?

Tags: unicode, eiffel

Evidently in python:
print u'\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f'

outputs:
Россия

How do I do this in Eiffel?

Answer (score 1):

On my linux OS, this code print exactly what you want:

```
make
        -- Initialisation of `Current'
    local
        l_utf_converter:UTF_CONVERTER
        l_string:STRING_32
    do
        create l_string.make_empty
        l_string.append_code (0x420)
        l_string.append_code (0x43e)
        l_string.append_code (0x441)
        l_string.append_code (0x441)
        l_string.append_code (0x438)
        l_string.append_code (0x44f)
        print(l_utf_converter.utf_32_string_to_utf_8_string_8 (l_string))
    end
```

In a nutshell, STRING_32 use UTF-32 and the linux console use UTF-8. The UTF_CONVERTER class can be use to convert UTF-32 to UTF-8.

I do not know if it is possible on a Windows console.

Comment: Doesn't really fit in a nutshell, but it works.  Thanks.  (I upvoted, but I don't have enough reputation to count, I guess.)

Answer (score 1):

An example at the first page of [eiffel.org](https://eiffel.org/) (at the time of writintg) suggests the following code:

```
io.put_string_32 ("[
   Hello!
   Â¡Hola!
   Bonjour!
   こんにちは！
   Здравствуйте!
   Γειά σου!
]")
```

It is supported since *EiffelStudio 20.05*. (I tested the example with *EiffelStudio 22.05*.)

In this particular case, using `print` instead of `io.put_string_32` works as well. However, in some boundary cases, when all character codes in the string are below 256, you may need to specify the string type explicitly:

```
print ({STRING_32} "Zürich") -- All character code points are below 256.
```

Of course, you can write the character code points explicitly:

```
io.put_string_32 ("%/0x041f/%/0x0440/%/0x0438/%/0x0432/%/0x0435/%/0x0442/%/0x0021/")
```

The output code page defaults to UTF-8 for text files and the current console code page for `CONSOLE` (the standard object type of `io`). If needed, the default encoding can be changed to any other encoding:

```
io.standard_default.set_encoding ({SYSTEM_ENCODINGS}.console_encoding)
```